# Is it possible to calculate the angle between two observers given their angles to three of the same points?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Given the image below, is it possible to calculate the angles E and/or F given the angles $A,B,C$ and $D$?

The situation is as follows:

- Two observers each measure the angle between point $1$ and point $2$ (these angles are $A$ and $C$ respectively) and point $2$ and point $3$ ($B$ and $D$).
- The three points are the same real-world points for both observers, but the exact location (distance etc) of both points is unknown.

Is it possible to calculate the angle $E$ and/or $F$ here? It feels like this should be possible but I'm not entirely sure if and how. The reason I think this is that given the two measured angles, there's only one possible position for the observer to be (if the points were in a straight line, there could be another point on the other side of the line but let's disregard that for now). Given that we have the two observer points for which we know that there is only one possible location, it feels like it should be possible to then calculate the angle between the two of them.

[image: Sketch of measured angles]

Comment: Even with points $1,2,3$ not in a straight line, there may still be two possible locations for each observer. But the bigger problem is, if you don't know the distances and angles between points $1,2,3$ then you cannot reconstruct the locations where the observers can be relative to those points. (Actually just the three angles of the triangle with vertices $1,2,3$, each angle identified with a vertex, would be enough; distances are unnecessary.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angles $A$,$B$,$C$ and $D$ doesn't determine the angles $E$ or $F$
[image]

[image]